# Approximation to harmonic map.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

> Suppose $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is bounded and smooth, $g\in H^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{S}^{2})$. For $\varepsilon>0$ and $u\in H^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3})$ define the Ginzburg-Landau energy$$E_{\varepsilon}(u)=\int_{\Omega}\dfrac{1}{2}\lvert\nabla u\rvert^{2}+\dfrac{1}{4\varepsilon^{2}}\big{(}1-\lvert u\rvert^{2}\big{)}^{2}\,dx.$$Prove that$$E_{\varepsilon}(u)=\min_{v\in H_{g}^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3})}E_{\varepsilon}(v)$$has a minimizer $u_{\varepsilon}\in H_{g}^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3})$ and $E_{\varepsilon}(u_{\varepsilon})\leq C$, $C>0$ is independent of $\varepsilon$, where$$H_{g}^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3}):=\big{\{}u\in H^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3}):\ \left. u\right| _{\partial\Omega}=\left. g\right| _{\partial\Omega}\big{\}}.$$Then prove there is a sequence $\varepsilon_{k}\rightarrow0$ and $u\in H_{g}^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{S}^{2})$ such that $u_{\varepsilon_{k}}\rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $H^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3})$ and strongly in $L^{2}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3})$.

I have proved the first one. While for the second, I gauss the $u$ we required is the solution of$$E(u)=\min_{v\in H_{g}^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{S}^{2})}E(v),$$where$$E(v)=\int_{\Omega}\dfrac{1}{2}\lvert\nabla v\rvert^{2}\,dx.$$According to Evans, it is also a weak solution of$$\begin{cases}
 \Delta u+\lvert\nabla u\rvert^{2}u=0\ \text{in}\ \Omega\\
 \left. u\right| _{\partial\Omega}=\left. g\right| _{\partial\Omega}.\\
 \end{cases} $$Then for $\varepsilon_{k}\rightarrow0$, we have $\lvert u_{\varepsilon_{k}}\rvert^{2}\rightarrow1$ and $\lvert\nabla u_{\varepsilon_{k}}\rvert^{2}\rightarrow\lvert\nabla u\rvert^{2}$, i.e. $u_{\varepsilon_{k}}\rightarrow u$ in $H^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3})$ and strongly in $L^{2}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3})$. Meanwhile, since $H^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{3})$ is a Hilbert space, there exists a subsequence of $\varepsilon_{k}$ (still denote as $\varepsilon_{k}$) such that $u_{\varepsilon_{k}}\rightharpoonup u$ weakly. But there is a problem that the solution of$$E(u)=\min_{v\in H_{g}^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{S}^{2})}E(v),$$may not be unique(or are there any method to prove it?). So I wonder if my thoughts make sense. Any other approaches are welcome, too. Appreciate in advance.

Comment: Unlike for $E_\epsilon$, it's really unclear that the direct method you are trying works on $E$, because it is not clear that your $u \in H^1(\Omega; S^2)$: the target constraint is not convex and you are trying to use weak convergence. But if you are just trying to answer the question at the beginning, it's not clear why you are minimizing $E$ at all; you just need to show that your $\{u_\epsilon\}$ is precompact in the relevant topologies.

Comment: @user378654 Thanks for your comment. Indeed I learned from Evans’  8.4.3 that $u\in H^1(\Omega;\mathbb{S}^2)$, but he doesn’t prove the uniqueness.